# Spring LdapContextSource authentication with GSSAPI

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ldap, gssapi, spring-security-ldap

Is it possible to authenticate Spring LDAP context (LdapContextSource)  source with GSSAPI

```
   Map<String, Object> baseEnvironmentProperties = new HashMap<String,Object>();
LdapContextSource contextSource= new LdapContextSource();
    .....
baseEnvironmentProperties.put( Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "GSSAPI");
contextSource.setBaseEnvironmentProperties(baseEnvironmentProperties);
```

Spring Documentation discusses only about DefaultTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy and ExternalDirContextAuthenticationStrategy- EXTERNAL SASL TLS

Comment: Have you finally been able to achieve that requirement? Thank you